# Kindly Help me out the javascript code

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
                {
                    IncomeDetails.initIncomeForm();
                });
```

The above code is written in XSL File.

Can anybody explain me what does this Javascript code means ?
Is IncomeDetail is class ?  what is it scope ? what is its use?

I find in my code this code is definded app.js file as

```
IncomeDetails = {

initIncomeForm : function()
{...some code here
```

what does it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IncomeDetails` is an **object** and `initIncomeForm` is a **method** therein.

This syntax

```
IncomeDetails = {
   initIncomeForm : function() {
```

is how you declare an object literal in JavaScript, though the author may have been a bit sloppy.  Assuming IncomeDetails is not previously declared elsewhere, leaving off the `var` here will cause this object to an implicit global variable, and therefore, to answer your other question, global in scope.

Comment: Thanks can u provide me link where i can find the detail information about the same.

Comment: About what same?  About creating JavaScript object literals?

Comment: @ZunedAhmed - this looks like a decent starter.  There are plenty of other tutorials online all over  :) http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml

Comment: where i could find about these syntax. I mean i precise detail knowledge of jquery and javascript

Comment: @ZunedAhmed - I don't have any location off hand.  Bear Biebalt's book on jQuery was great, as far as JavaScript syntax, there are lots of online resources you could check out

Answer (score 0):

The code means that once the DOM is ready, method initIncomeForm() of object IncomeDetails is executed. The code you're presenting is formed using [Singleton pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript) . It is an easy way for defining objects with multiple public and also private variables and methods.

The scope of a method is defined by the place in the code the method is defined. So in your case the scope of IncomeDetails object's methods is the surroundings of IncomeDetails object definition, in app.js.

In your case initIncomeForm does some initialization to the object. Probably it returns you another singleton object with methods and variables to access, but that is just a guess and can't be read from your code.

IncomeDetails is not a class in the strictest definition, but certainly acts as such. I suggest you to take a look at the article linked above, it explains different javascript patterns quite well.